# Command line loop through directories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a batch file that will be run on a parent directory and will loop through subdirectories **removing all but the newest 3 files** from each subdirectory. What I have now recurses through the subdirectories but only skips the 3 newest files that it comes across, not the three newest files in each subdir. I think I need another loop in the code, but need help with where and what it should be. Help!

What I have so far - just ECHOing the output for now as a test.

```
@echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%F in (
    'dir /s /a-d /o-d /b') do ECHO del "%%F" /f
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /D %%i in (*) do (
   pushd "%%~i"
   for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%F in (
       'dir /a-d /o-d /b') do ECHO del /f "%%~F"
   popd
   )
popd
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed... gracias!